# Is there anything like Quandl for social sciences or health services research?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, survey

I would love to see something that gathers all the public data, as Quandl does for finance and macroeconomics, but for social science and health services research in general. I am aware of www.asdfree.org but I'm asking for something as user friendly as Quandl.

Comment: i'm not sure how this relates to open data in particular vs. a lengthy list of feature requests. i wanted to give this the benefit of the doubt, but considering the first response, i should have commented earlier, so i apologize. voting to close for now.

Comment: Instead of dropping a new, can you describe the feature of the service that you like to see?